# Telethon - How do I setup a simple web app (using Quart for example)?

Tags: python, telethon

I'm doing a small project written in PHP (Laravel framework) and a part of project has to do telegram messaging. I couldn't find any MTProto library written in PHP that is well supported & well documented. I know there is MadelineProto but it's missing many features and it ain't big and loved like how Telethon is.

So I thought maybe I could just setup a simple python script (even though I have zero experience with Python) where it provides a simple API that I can reach from the PHP side and call those methods and use them. (Let me know if there are any better solutions)

My first thought was to use Flask with Telethon but as you may know Telethon is a asyncio library and it doesn't integrate with Flask easily. And I found about this helpful [link](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/tree/master/telethon_examples#quart_loginpy) which explains some stuff and talks about Quart and provides a (supposedly) working example.

I tried to follow it like so (Python 3.8) :

```py
from telethon import TelegramClient, connection
import hypercorn.asyncio
from quart import Quart

api_id = x
api_hash = x

client = TelegramClient('telegram', api_id, api_hash)

app = Quart(__name__)

@app.before_serving
async def startup():
    await client.connect()


@app.after_serving
async def cleanup():
    await client.disconnect()

@app.route('/')
async def hello_world():
    await client.send_message('me', 'Hello World')
    return 'Message Sent!'

async def main():
    await hypercorn.asyncio.serve(app, hypercorn.Config())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    client.loop.run_until_complete(main())
```

I know in the quart [example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/quart_login.py) they manually do the login but I don't need that. In my case I'm only working with 1 global client and I already logged it in using Telethon built-in interactive login (by running `python run.app` for the first time where it creates the session file)
Anyway the hello world message does gets sent but the problem is I'm getting all kind of different errors in the console output.

Like if I try to stop the app using (CTRL + C) after running `python run.py` I get this error:

`RuntimeError: no running event loop
Task was destroyed but it is pending`

Or if I try to run the code using `hypercorn run:app` I get these 2 errors immediately and the app won't even start:

`got Future <Future pending> attached to a different loop
RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'open_connection' was never awaited`

(I removed all the traceback for the sake of keeping the question clean)

Here are my questions:

1. I don't know if I'm doing the [example](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/quart_login.py) wrong maybe I'm missing something?
2. Should I use a different library other than Quart? or it wouldn't make any difference?
3. Maybe I approached the problem the wrong way and I should use a different solution to have Telethon work with PHP ?

Comment: [An older version of the quart example uses a global client](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/2a7d4317bd20c171a36abe93aac417a460643c99/telethon_examples/quart_login.py), which may help you.

Comment: *> I removed all the traceback for the sake of keeping the question clean*. This traceback is necessary for anyone who wants to properly investigate the problem before giving an answer, and you should include it even if you think it's unnecessary.

Comment: @Lonami Thanks a lot for your input! I used the link you posted (the very last 2 lines) and now I'm getting less errors and it's working better. I might be jumping to conclusions but it looks like my problem is gone. If you post your comment as an answer along with an explanation on why the "older version" of quart example works better I will gladly accept it. Also If you still need the traceback I will update my post and have it added. Sorry for not adding it in the first place, you know in SO ppl usually run away from questions with tons of lines of errors.

Comment: Also the only error I'm getting at the moment is after I run `hypercorn run:app` (and it works fine compared to last time where it wouldn't even start the app) when I try to stop it using CTRL + C it gives me a `Lifespan failure in startup. 'Event loop is closed'`

Comment: `hypercon` may be using a different (new) event loop, not sure, haven't used it much myself.

Comment: Same case as me. I have used MadelineProto an half year, but then the error log is much harder to read than telethon. My missing piece is the PHP integration with telethon. Hope that the [quart_login](https://github.com/LonamiWebs/Telethon/blob/master/telethon_examples/quart_login.py) help :)